# Permission Denied If I try to execute a bash script via SSH to a remote server

Tags: linux, ssh

I am able to make an ssh connection without password to that remote server. Also if i execute a single line command instead of a bash script, it works without any problems. But if i try to execute a bash script via ssh, it says

```
bash: /home/username/script.sh: Permission denied
```

How can i fix this? I can execute single line commands via ssh without any problems.

Comment: Is the executable bit set on the script? Also how do you execute the command? `ssh`-login, then command or `ssh foo@bar "command"`?

Comment: is `/home/username/script.sh` executable on remote hosts ? (e.g. has flag `x` set )

Comment: @Archemar yes i also did chmod u+x script.sh

Comment: @FelixJN i execute it like "ssh username@remotehost /home/username/script.sh

Comment: @maxine please show output `ls -l script.sh`. Did you by any chance copy it there from you local PC with the same username and assumed it to have the same permissions remotely?

Comment: @FelixJN `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 Nov  3 14:01 LastBootUpTime.sh
`

Comment: Maxine please [edit] your question to include information. If you put it in the comments it can get missed or sometimes even accidentally deleted

Comment: Thanks all I guess i solved it.

Comment: @maxine Please either elaborate how you did so, so others may take this as reference, or delete the question if you feel that others would not profit from your findings. It is always annoying to find someone with the same problem and a mere "I solved it" as the last comment with no solution provided.

Comment: @FelixJN thanks to roaima said it in detail. I gave it execution permission to local server but forgot to give it to the everyone. 

i solved it with the command of "chmod 777 script.sh"

Comment: @maxine "chmod 755 script.sh" would be probably more suitable mode, unless you really have the need to set 777. With 777 everyone can make writes (change) your script.

Comment: @Damir thanks a lot. that will be useful for me. i am still new at linux.

Comment: @maxine Welcome. I'm glad my additional info is useful for you. Welcome to amazing Linux world :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to run this:

```
/home/username/LastBootupTime.sh
```

and it has these permissions:

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 42 Nov  3 14:01 LastBootUpTime.sh
```

then only `root` will be able to do so. Everyone else will get the error `bash: /home/username/LastBootUpTime.sh: Permission denied`.

This is because the permissions are such that:

- `rwx` - the owner (root in this instance) can read/write/execute the script
- `r--` - the group (root group in this instance) can read but neither write nor execute the script
- `r--` - everyone else can read but neither write nor execute the script

Now, in your case you've explicitly specified this command:

```
bash /home/user/LastBootupTime.sh
```

so although you need read permission you *do not* need execute permission. Therefore there's another reason for the error message. It's most likely that one of the directories is inaccessible to users.

Perhaps your real command is this:

```
bash /root/LastBootupTime.sh
```

In this instance only the `root` user can access the `/root` directory, so everyone else will get a permission denied error. The solution is to put the script into a suitably accessible directory (I use `/usr/local/bin` on my systems; other people prefer `/opt/bin`, but you could place it anywhere that worked for you).

Comment: The `bash: script.sh: Permission Denied` message also turns up when executing a script with shebang instruction and no execetuable permissions. @Maxime did not run `bash script.sh` as written. Maybe this might confuse a reader.

Comment: thanks "chmod 777 script.sh" solved my problem. this answer is approved. sadly i am a guest user i am not able to give an upvote. but approved the answer

Comment: @maxine `chmod 777` is a really bad idea - it allows anyone on the server to edit your script. Better is `chmod u=rwx,go=rx` (equivalent to `chmod 755` but easier to read)

Comment: @roaima thanks a lot for that info. i am still new at linux and learn slowly. this will help me a lot in the future.